# Option Button Existing in two group boxes

Tags: vba, radio-button

I'm trying to create an array of option buttons (or check boxes if you find that works better) where only one option can be selected in each row and column.
I'm trying to do this so that a user can choose an order in which a certain list goes.

The following code takes the column headers in an excel sheet, and creates bunch of option buttons x columns across and x rows down.

```
Sub Option_Buttons()

    Dim str As String

    lCol = Sheets("Headers").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim OpBtn() As OptionButton
    ReDim OpBtn(lCol, lCol) As OptionButton
    Dim GrBx() As GroupBox
    ReDim GrBx(lCol) As GroupBox

    Dim i
    Dim j
 '
    For i = 1 To lCol
        Set GrBx(i) = Sheets("OPBTN").GroupBoxes.Add(Cells(i, 1).Left, _ 
                          Cells(i, 1).Top, lCol * 50, 17.25)
        With GrBx(i)
            .Caption = ""
            '.Visible = False
        End With

        For j = 1 To lCol
            Set OpBtn(i, j) = Sheets("OPBTN").OptionButtons.Add _
                           (Cells(i,j).Left, Cells(i, j).Top, 72, 17.25)
            str = Sheets("Turf").Cells(1, j)
            check = OpBtn(i, j).Value

            With OpBtn(i, j)
                .Caption = str
                .Value = xlOff '
                .LinkedCell = "'OData'!" & Sheets("OData").Cells(i, 1).Address
                .Display3DShading = False
        End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Is there any way I can make it so that only one option can exist in each row AND column? (so if there are 5 column headers, there are 25 option buttons of which only 5 can be selected).

Is there any way to deal with the option that a user doesn't want a header selected?

I'm trying to avoid all possible uses of the controls tab because this is part of a macro that needs to be used by completely excel illiterate people and needs to be applied to highly variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using checkboxes.  The key was to name the checkboxes using R1C1 notation and assigning a macro (`ManageCheckBoxes`) to all the checkboxes.  After identifying what checkbox was clicked using `Application.Caller` I iterate over all the checkboxes parsing their names to identify which rows and columns they are in.

[image]

---

```
Sub Option_Buttons()

    Dim str As String
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim check As CheckBox
    lCol = Sheets("Headers").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    With Sheets("OPBTN")
        For r = 1 To lCol
            For c = 1 To lCol
                Set check = .CheckBoxes.Add(.Cells(r, c).Left, .Cells(r, c).Top, 72, 17.25)
                str = Sheets("Turf").Cells(r, c)

                With check
                    .Caption = str
                    .Value = xlOff                    '
                    .Name = "R" & r & "C" & c
                    .Display3DShading = False
                    .OnAction = "ManageCheckBoxes"
                End With
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub ManageCheckBoxes()
    Dim arrCaller As Variant, arrCheck As Variant
    Dim check As CheckBox, ckCaller As CheckBox

    arrCaller = getRC(Application.Caller)

    With Sheets("OPBTN")
        Set ckCaller = .CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        For Each check In .CheckBoxes
            If ckCaller.Name <> check.Name Then
                If check.Name Like "R#*C#*" Then
                    arrCheck = getRC(check.Name)
                    If arrCheck(0) = arrCaller(0) Or arrCheck(1) = arrCaller(1) Then

                        check.Value = False

                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Function getRC(sName As String)
    Dim a(1) As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Split(sName, "C")
    a(0) = Right(arr(0), Len(arr(0)) - 1)
    a(1) = arr(1)
    getRC = a
End Function
```

Comment: That's perfect!! Well almost. The only thing I should add is that this only works if the number of headers is in the single digits. That's because this line:

    If check.Name Like "R#C#" Then

only checks single digits. but this gives me an excellent framework to go off.
Thanks

Comment: My quick fix because I doubt this will ever have more than 99 options is:

    If check.Name Like "R#C#" Or check.Name Like "R#C##" Or check.Name Like "R##C#" Or check.Name Like "R##C##" Then

but if you have a better solution I'm all ears

Comment: Good point I edit my answer changing the `Like` comparison string to `"R#*C#*"`.  This should account for all instances.

Answer (score 0):

use GroupName property of option buttons. GroupName property determines the group of option button. user will be able to select only one option button from the group.
Set same groupname for your five option buttons and same for other five.

For Example :

- Option1 GroupName: grp1
- Option2 GroupName: grp1
- Option3 GroupName: grp2
- Option4 GroupName: grp2

in the above case user will be able to select one from option1 and option2. one button from option3 and option4.

Comment: The OP is using Forms controls which do not have the GroupName property.  Furthermore, he  stipulates: `where only one option can be selected in each row and column`